# How to get rid of matted hair in cats

Tags: cats, grooming

I have a Persian male cat. He has many hairballs at his lower part (near the tail). I have searched for solutions from Google, and got some solutions, like:

1 "Give specific cat food which is specially used for hairballs." For nearly four months I have been giving him Meow Persian cat food for hairballs.

2 "Not properly combing can be another issue." I am setting his hair daily but still no improvement!

Also, I have cut the large hairballs (which I can). But some are remaining, at the lower part. And it is very painful for him when I touch those for cutting. Because those are attached to his skin.

Kindly show me the way to get rid of them.

EDITED: I had confusion between hairballs and hair matting. So actually my pet has hair mats, not hairballs.

Comment: The term "hairballs" when applied to cats typically refers to the hair which they cough up after swallowing it while grooming themselves, and not to balls of matted fur in their coat. As such, I doubt that there's a cat-food remedy for your issue.

Comment: @brhans, "As such, I doubt that there's a cat food remedy for your issue".. Can you help me to suggest proper food for it?

Comment: I agree, you're confusing hairballs and hair matting. It sounds like you are trying to ask about hair matting, not hairballs, which is a different problem. The only solution is to try to work the mat out, but there are various tools and techniques you can use to accomplish this. https://www.petful.com/grooming/how-remove-mats-long-haired-cat/ You can also take your cat to a groomer if you're not confident you can do this safely.

Comment: There are cat foods which can help with hairballs, but what your cat has are not hairballs, so a different food won't fix them.

Comment: Thank you so much, #Kai and #brhans , to let me know the difference between hairballs and hair matting. And also thanks @Kai for sharing the link. I have tried the comb. And it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix matted fur you need to get a cat brush. The one I use is similar to this one.[image]

You need to brush the cat a couple of times a week after your cat has gotten rid of the matted fur to avoid it coming back.

When you brush your cat, do not force the cat to stay. It is better to brush the cat for a short time and repeat it after the cat has had a break.

If it is a lot of fur that is matted, you might take the cat to a vet or to a cat groomer. The fur might need to be removed by shaving or cutting the affected area.

Most cats really like to be brushed, but take it slow and gentle and be careful when brushing the belly area or you might get hurt. It is often best to let the cat stand on all four legs with you reaching around from above while brushing the belly area.

You will be amazed at the amount of fur that comes off in a short time, but your cat will love to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Persian cats are notoriously high maintenance with regards to their coat.

They need daily, or at least weekly grooming.  If the cat was not trained to accept/appreciate this from a young age you will need to coerce them slowly.

Once mats have developed, they need to be cut away before normal grooming can start.

For a cat with a severe case of matting, it may be necessary to take them to a vet to sedate the cat and clip the entire coat.

This is the time to start grooming the cat on a regular basis. Make him feel comfortable, and associate this activity with positive attention. If the cat is not happy, keep the sessions short. Do keep the cat in your lap and pet it/stroke it until it is relaxed.